# How should I format and parse a DateTimeFormatter object?

Tags: kotlin, java-time, datetimeformatter

I am trying to parse a date in `parseServerTimeOffsetDateTime()`, but I keep getting errors. Can't seem to make it work.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. For some reason the function keeps returning a Unit data type or TemporalAccessor if I try to parse the function with default `parse` function.
   I tried converting it into a String or DataTimeFormatter and similar data types but in those cases it shows errors in try/catch block like a type missmatch and it won't compile.
2. I checked in documentation but am still unclear what TemporalAccessor is.
3. I thought of writing my own parser `TimeParser`, but I am not sure how I should implement it. Since the format of the date is `2022-05-24T07:52:03Z` I thought of putting  'T' and 'Z' as a character where it should be parsed.

```
private val serverTimeFormatterOffsetDateTimeFormatter =
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME 

private val fallbackServerTimeFormatterOffsetDateTime =
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME

fun OffsetDateTime.toServerDateFormatOffsetDateTime() = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")

fun OffsetDateTime.toServerTimeFormatOffsetDateTime() =
    serverTimeFormatterOffsetDateTimeFormatter.format(this)

fun String.parseServerTimeOffsetDateTime() = try {
    serverTimeFormatterOffsetDateTimeFormatter.TimeParser(this)
} catch (pe: ParseException) {
    fallbackServerTimeFormatterOffsetDateTime.TimeParser(this)
}

fun DateTimeFormatter.TimeParser(time: String) {
//    Haven't done anything yet here
    val delimeter = "T"
    val delimeter2 = "Z"
    //  code for parsing
}
```

How should I format and parse a `DateTimeFormatter` object?

Comment: If you want to parse a `String` into an `OffsetDateTime` using a custom `DateTimeFormatter`, then use [`OffsetDateTime#parse(CharSequence,DateTimeFormatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter)).

Comment: Perhaps you want `fun String.parseServerTimeOffsetDateTime() = OffsetDateTime.parse(this, /* the formatter */)`?

Comment: Is there a way to format it as a "day date_of_the_day month", for example `Tue 24 May` ?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to parse a `String` or format an `OffsetDateTime`? Keep in mind that `format = OffsetDateTime -> String` and `parse = String -> OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: I want to keep it in OffsetDateTime and format it later. So I guess "parse" for now. I guess this answers my question.
Thanks!

Comment: Note you can format a date-time object using any pattern you want, so long as that date-time object has the necessary information. But I'm not sure you could parse `"Tue 24 May"` into an `OffsetDateTime`, as I don't think there's enough information in the string. Though I don't have much experience with "optional" data in patterns (so maybe it is possible?).

Comment: I will test it, but I think that is a separate issue. Probably going to format it in a separate function in another class.

Comment: Just want to make sure, because I know some people get confused with this, but know that `OffsetDateTime` does not have a format. It's simply data that represents a date-time with an offset. In other words, no matter the format of the `String` you parse, the `OffsetDateTime` does not "know" that format. That's why we have `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting and parsing.